# Dart SDK not install

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I want to get started with flutter web so I am trying to install dart-sdk for windows (stable version Link: https://gekorm.com/dart-windows/) but it doesn't download.it always show a message,download failed:The operation timed out.

Answer (score 0):

actually you don't need to install dart SDK separately, because flutter SDK comes with dart SDK together in one zip.
to start flutter web app you need to change flutter channel to beta and enable web configuration :

```sh
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
flutter config --enable-web
```

or I recommend downloading the flutter beta SDK from [here:](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/releases)

and use separately it from your stable SDK

you can find more info about flutter web [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)